# Moving animation frame by frame

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I am working on a PPT presentation in order to teach some concepts. On some of these slides, I have animations, all built with PPT (circles, rectangles, text, etc.). Now, I was able to find a way to stop the animation in the middle and to start it again by using **ppSlideShowPaused** and **ppSlideShowRunning**. Because of the nature of the animation (there is a lot going on...), I would like to be able, when it is paused, to move the animation frame by frame, forward and backward, so I can explain stuff at the same time.

In the same way, are you aware of a way to include a slider that would enable me to go to a specific part of the animation?

I searched and could not find anything. Any ideas how I could do that?

Thanks

Rick

Comment: PowerPoint has no native way of doing this but it might help to use an add-in by Massimo Rimondini, PPSpliT, that breaks up your animated slide into individual step-by-step slides:  http://www.maxonthenet.altervista.org/ppsplit.php

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg Thanks you Steve for your answer. That is what I gathered. I will take a look at the link you suggested.